# C++ deep copy const char * inside of class array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, deep-copy

So i have problem Im making class. In this class im supposed to have array of some data. I have no problem with assigning and creating new data with for example x2.NewAccount("123456" , 1000); this works fine the problem is when im trying to create data with string that is addressed to some variable. I know something about deep copying but I have no clue how to programm = operator in my case + i thought that strcpy but thats not working aswell.

PS: Its a school program so please dont judge me for not using headers and using bunch of includes that Im not using in code. Its made by my school and Im not allowed to change them + add them (I know that with string from c++ it would be much easier.).
Thanks for any help.

```
#ifndef __PROGTEST__
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
#endif /* __PROGTEST__ */

struct data_history{
    int money = 0;
    bool Income;
    const char * UnStr;
    const char * to_from;
};

struct client{
    const char * accID;
    int Balance;
    int def_bal;
    data_history * history;
    int in_index = 0;
    int in_cap = 10;

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output , client p){
        output << p.accID << ":" << endl << "   " << p.def_bal << endl;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < p.in_index ; i++){
            if (p.history[i].Income == false)
                output << " - " << abs(p.history[i].money) << ", to: " << p.history[i].to_from << ", sign: " << p.history[i].UnStr << endl;
            else
                output << " + " <<abs(p.history[i].money) << ", from: " << p.history[i].to_from << ", sign: " << p.history[i].UnStr << endl;
        }
        output << " = " << p.Balance << endl;
        return output;
    }
};

class CBank
{
public:
    int cap = 10;
    int index = 0;
    client * database;
    ~CBank(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < index ; i++)
                delete[] database[i].history;
        delete[]database;
    }
    CBank(){
        database = new client[cap];
    }
    bool NewAccount ( const char * accID, int initialBalance ){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < index ; i ++)
            if (accID == database[i].accID) {
                return false;
            }
        //strcpy (database[index].accID , accID );  // Im getting errors while compileing (cuz I was using const char * for database.accID when i chenged it i got program crash. 
        database[index].accID = accID;
        database[index].Balance = initialBalance;
        database[index].def_bal = initialBalance;
        database[index].in_cap = 10;
        database[index].history = new data_history[database[index].in_cap];
        index ++;
        return true;
    }
    client Account (const char * accID ){
        const char * input  =accID;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < index ; i++){
            if (database[i].accID == input )
                return database[i];
        }
        throw "error";
    }
    void print (){
        for (int i = 0 ; i  < index ; i ++) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << i << " = "<< " ID = " << database[i].accID << " | Balance = " << database[i].Balance << endl;
            cout << "===Account history ===\n\n";
            for (int y = 0 ; y < database[i].in_index; y++) {
                cout << "Was it for him? : " << boolalpha << database[i].history[y].Income
                    << "\nHow much : " << database[i].history[y].money << "\nUnique string : "
                    << database[i].history[y].UnStr << "\nfrom/to: " << database[i].history[y].to_from << endl << endl;
            }
        }
    }

private:

};


#ifndef __PROGTEST__
int main ( void )
{
    char accCpy[100], debCpy[100], credCpy[100], signCpy[100];
    CBank x2;
    strncpy ( accCpy, "123456", sizeof ( accCpy ) );
    assert ( x2 . NewAccount ( accCpy, 1000 ) );
    x2 . print();
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    strncpy ( accCpy, "987654", sizeof ( accCpy ) );
    assert ( x2 . NewAccount ( "987654", -500 ) );
    x2 . print();
}
#endif /* __PROGTEST__ */
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if you plan to learn c++ and not only want to solve the assignment, then I highly suggest learning it from a good book and - at least regarding the style of the given code - forget what you were taught in the course after you passed it.

Comment: `client::accID` is just a pointer. You never initialize it to point anywhere. You need a constructor for you `client` class that allocates memory for `accID` (along with a copy copy constructor, assignment operator, and deconstructor), or you need to change it to `char accID[10]` (or 20 or 30 or however much space you need). The same goes for `data_history`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `database[index].accID = accID;` you are only doing a shallow copy (and relying on the caller to keep this memory valid as the pointer may be accessed).

You've correctly identified that you need to preform a deep-copy, but `client::accID` is just a pointer, but you may not copy into it until you initialize it to point to some memory.

One way of doing this is to dynamically allocate and manage `client::accID` similar to how you are dynamically allocating and managing `client::history`.

Instead of `strcpy (database[index].accID , accID );` or `database[index].accID = accID;`, try:

```
size_t bufsize = strlen(accID) + 1;
char *buf = new char[bufsize];
memcpy(buf, accID, bufsize);
database[index].accID = buf;
```

and in the destructor add:

```
delete[] database[i].accID
```

As others have pointed out, this style of C++ programing is very error prone and not looked upon well by the community. This manually memory management can be easily avoided by using the standard library classes. Even after making the changes above, your program will run into undefined behavior if you start copying `CBank` objects.

Even if you don't have to for your assignment, you should consider trying to rewrite this as an exercise with:

- `std::string` instead of C-strings for `accID;`
- `std::vector` instead of the `data_history` array

---

Also FYI:

```
if (database[i].accID == input )
```

Will not do what expect with c-strings...